# htaccess Rewrite cond not working for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

My htaccess file has the following rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I want to add condition for subdomains so subdomain.example.com can be browsed as subdomain.example.com i tried few condition but they were redirecting to  main domain.
I am using codeigniter framework (may be not relevent )

Answer (score 3):

You van just add an extra condition.

This should work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```